# sort by date in caml query

Tags: sharepoint

I want to sort my list items by date:

I m using

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='SortDate' Ascending='True'/></Order By>
```

but its giving me results randomly.Is it possible to sort by date in CAML if not then if there is any other way to retrieve list items sorted on the basis of date....

Comment: Is your CAML correct? Closing tag is not the same as ending :) You must not have spaces in Order by tag.

Comment: Thats the not the problem it was mistake in copying pasting..my question is Can we sort by date using caml or no? I was trying executing query in U2U Caml query builder and I was looking at results...and it was not I as I was expecting

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can sort by date using CAML. To test it out try sorting on the Modified field to see if that gets you better results. Is your SortDate field an actual DateTime field, or is it something else like a string?

Comment: Its a string but I am keeping dates in it...because date can have any format....so is it possible to sort in any way?

Comment: Ahh... If your dates are strings they will be sorted alphabetically not chronologically. In order to get sorting correct they must all be formatted like yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: If there is any way to sort If my string is in Format mm/dd/yyyy